# bootstrap hidden-xs not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I just found out about hidden-xs, hidden-sm etc, so am trying it out for the first time..

How come this doesn't hide the review div on any screen size?

```
<div class="row hidden-sm">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
      <result-reviews [result]='selectedResult?.result.result'></result-reviews>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is more of my code:

```
<div class="modal-body">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-7">
            <div class="row">
               <div id="image-div" class="col-sm-5 col-lg-5">
                  <result-image [result]='selectedResult?.result.result'></result-image>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-7 col-lg-7">
                  <result-attributes [result]='selectedResult?.result.result'></result-attributes>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row hidden-sm">
               <div class="col-xs-12">
                  <result-reviews [result]='selectedResult?.result.result'></result-reviews>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div id="shops-section">
               <div id="map" #map></div>
               <ul>
                  <li *ngFor="let shop of selectedResult?.result.result.nearbyShops">
                     <div class="shop-details">
                        {{ shop.name }}
                     </div>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Which version of bootstrap are you using? In the bootstrap 4 alpha the hidden-xs classes (and sm, md, ...) have been replaced by hidden-xs-up or hidden-xs-down as explained here:
http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/

Comment: That was it! I'm using bootstrap 4. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It works with `d-none d-sm-block!` Try this if you want to hide the division.

For reference, this is the link [Getbootstrap Migration](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/)

Answer (score 2):

> How come this doesn't hide the review div on any screen size?

Read this part of the bootstrap documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

`hidden-sm` will only apply to sizes between 768 and 992px width.

Comment: But it never gets hidden on any screen size. I added hidden-xs hidden-md etc too and tested all screen sizes by resizing the browser window and none got hidden.

Comment: well, it *does* work as intended here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ALgJdm This is *your* code, with the only alteration that I added class `x` to your `hidden-sm` div to make it more obvious (displaying it as a ed rectangle). If you change the window size, the red rectangle will disappear when the width is between 768 and 992px.

Comment: Yeah. Something must be wrong with my bootstrap. But it's strange because i've been using it for a whole 4 website pages as it all works correctly except for hidden. I'm installed bootstrap via bower_components. I'm trying to use a CDN instead and it's not getting bootstrap properly.

Answer (score 0):

Since bootstrap v.4.0 (stable)

> All @screen- variables have been **removed** in v4.0.0. Use the media-breakpoint-up(), media-breakpoint-down(), or media-breakpoint-only() Sass mixins or the $grid-breakpoints Sass map instead.